# How do we access and respond to CloudFormation custom resources using an AWS Lambda function written in Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I have am AWS Lambda function written in Java that I would like to use as part of a response to an AWS CloudFormation function. Amazon provides [two detailed examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) on how to create a CloudFormation custom resource that returns its value based on an AWS Lambda function written in Node.js, however I have been having difficulty translating the Lambda examples into Java. How can we setup our AWS Java function so that it reads the value of the pre-signed S3 URL passed in as a parameter to the Lambda function from CloudFormation and send back our desired response to the waiting CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 14):

After back and forth conversation with AWS, here are some code samples I've created that accomplish this.

First of all, assuming you want to [leverage the predefined interfaces for creating Handlers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html), you can implement RequestsHandler and define the HandleRequest methods like so:

```
public class MyCloudFormationResponder implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, Object>{
    public Object handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input, Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `Map<String, Object>`is a Map of the values sent from your CloudFormation resource to the Lambda function. An example CF resource:

```
"MyCustomResource": {
  "Type" : "Custom::String",
  "Version" : "1.0",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:function:MyCloudFormationResponderLambdaFunction",
    "param1": "my value1",
    "param2": ["t1.micro", "m1.small", "m1.large"]
  }
}
```

can be analyzed with the following code

```
    String responseURL = (String)input.get("ResponseURL");
    context.getLogger().log("ResponseURLInput: " + responseURL);
    context.getLogger().log("StackId Input: " + input.get("StackId"));
    context.getLogger().log("RequestId Input: " + input.get("RequestId"));
    context.getLogger().log("LogicalResourceId Context: " + input.get("LogicalResourceId"));
    context.getLogger().log("Physical Context: " + context.getLogStreamName());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String,Object> resourceProps = (Map<String,Object>)input.get("ResourceProperties");
    context.getLogger().log("param 1: " + resourceProps.get("param1"));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>)resourceProps.get("param2");
    for(String s : myList){
        context.getLogger().log(s);
    }
```

The key things to point out here, beyond what is explained in the NodeJS examples in the AWS documentation are

- `(String)input.get("ResponseURL")` is the pre-signed S3 URL that you need to respond back to (more on this later)
- `(Map<String,Object>)input.get("ResourceProperties")` returns the map of your CloudFormation custom resource "Properties" passed into the Lambda function from your CF template. I provided a String and ArrayList as two examples of object types that can be returned, though several others are possible

In order to respond back to the CloudFormation template custom resource instantiation, you need to execute an HTTP PUT call back to the ResponseURL previously mentioned and include most of the following fields in the variable `cloudFormationJsonResponse`. Below is how I've done this

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(responseURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        JSONObject cloudFormationJsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        try {
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("Status", "SUCCESS");
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("PhysicalResourceId", context.getLogStreamName());
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("StackId", input.get("StackId"));
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("RequestId", input.get("RequestId"));
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("LogicalResourceId", input.get("LogicalResourceId"));
            cloudFormationJsonResponse.put("Data", new JSONObject().put("CFAttributeRefName", "some String value useful in your CloudFormation template"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.write(cloudFormationJsonResponse.toString());
        out.close();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        context.getLogger().log("Response Code: " + responseCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Of particular note is the node "Data" above which references an additional `com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject` in which I include any attributes that are required in my CloudFormation template. In this case, it would be retrieved in CF template with something like `{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MyCustomResource", "CFAttributeRefName" ] }`

Finally, you can simply `return null` since nothing would be returned from this function as it's the `HTTPUrlConnection` that actually responds to the CF call.

Comment: do you give any permissions for the bucket where the response is sent as I have a problem with reading the response back from the custom resource when I sent it to the bucket? My lambda is sending the data correctly and then CloudFormation hangs because it seems it never gets notified.

Comment: Awkwardly the request to responseURL fails with an error that I can't figure it out: <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
Have you encountered this and do you know what does it actually mean?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the current version of the AWS Java SDK does not have the JSONObject class any more.  However, there is a very similar class called JSONObject in org.json.

Comment: The events library (version 3.8.0) now has this event type implemented:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/CloudFormationCustomResourceEvent.java

Answer (score 0):

Neil,

I really appreciate your great documentation here. I would add a few things that I found useful:

input.get("RequestType") - This comes back as "Create", "Delete", etc. You can use this value to determine what to do when a stack is created, deleted, etc..

As far as security, I uploaded the Lambda Functions and set the VPC, subnets, and security group (default) manually so I can reuse it with several cloudformationn scripts. That seems to be working okay.

I created one Lambda function that gets called by the CF scripts and one I can run manually  in case the first one fails.

This excellent gradle aws plugin makes it easy to upload Java Lambda functions to AWS.

[Gradle AWS Plugin](https://github.com/classmethod/gradle-aws-plugin)